# Excel print =TODAY() as value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an `IF` formula that adds in todays date when there is content in a certain cell, this is part of a document to keep track of when new people are added to the database,

```
=IF($D166<>"", TODAY(), "")
```

Is it possible to print the current days date as a value, not formula, so when I return the next day the values don't all update?

Comment: macro is there.. tell me exactly what and how u want.. will try to provide the macro accordingly..

Comment: I thought about using a macro, just wondered if there was a formula way, so the desired outcome is when I insert some text into the next available cell in column D, todays date is printed in column S.
e.g. I type "User1" in D165, then S165 reads 05/11/2014.

Comment: How about to copy that cell and paste it in same cell as "Value"? It is not possible that a macro program could guess the value of a certain cell will be modified in the future or not. There are two choices, use certain macro when you are sure the contents of certain cell is fixed, or , copy & past-as-value when you want fix the date at the cell.

Comment: okay so whats the problem in formula?? what u want if modify the `D165, S165` should not update the date??

Comment: Yes thats what it does at present, but if I update D165 on the 5/11/2014, S165 reads 5/11/2014, however when i return the day after, the 6/11/2014, S165 should still read 5/11/2014, but it doesn't, it updates with each day, rather than staying on the date it was entered.

Comment: @Fumu7 I think they are my only options, just asked in case there was something I had overlooked.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/69908/making-excel-formulas-only-evaluate-once might help. Not tested though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open new excel file..

From the bottom tab select your sheet say **Sheet1** right click > **View Code** > Paste the below code..

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 4 Then
          Target.Worksheet.Cells(Target.Row, 19) = Format(Now(), "DD-MMM-YYYY")
    End If
End Sub
```

and save the file..

---

**While saving remember you have to save the file as Macro Enabled excel .XLSM**  Now if you change the Column `D` it will enter the Date in `S` column and will not change if you reopen the file..

---

I have uploaded the file.. you can download the sample file from give link.. [MyTacTics.Blogspot.in](http://mytactics.blogspot.in/p/downloadingpage.html?DownloadId=0Bxxluya0NKB2QlBLVVRyVm5WZ3M)